# Can I change the inputs of a function that passes reference arguments into pointers and still have it work (C, C++)?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

So I have this function prototype within a C++ header file I was given:

```
extern LIBRARY_API BOOL read(unsigned int in_one, unsigned int & value);
```

But I'm running it via a MATLAB mex file, so it may have to be in C, not C++. Since references are a C++ only thing, someone suggested changing the function prototype into a pointer argument. Then I might have something like this:

```
extern LIBRARY_API BOOL read(unsigned int in_one, unsigned int * value);
```

And then in the mex file, I would make sure that I created **unsigned int *value** instead of **unsigned int value** and dereferenced it after running the read function.

However, I'm worried that (1) I may be referencing/dereferencing one thing too many (or not enough), and (2) I won't be able to do this because I can't change the actual source code and changing the prototype will just cause a mismatch between instantiation and definition.

So *assuming* that I can somehow change the definition to match the header, would my pointer function above be a valid substitution? And if I can't change the source code, is there a substitution that I could make that would be possible with C? Like a reference C-substitute that would still allow for the same definition?

Comment: A subversive approach is to use `read(unsigned int in_one, unsigned int  value[1]`.  The calling code uses `unsigned v[1]; v[0] = foo(); read(in_one, v);` and `read()` uses `*value = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want would probably work in practice, but is not really standard conforming (and depends upon the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) & the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)).

I would recommend instead to code a trivial stub function (which calls the original one), e.g.

```
/// assume that `read` is declared like in your question (first declaration)
extern "C" BOOL my_read(unsigned int in_one, unsigned int * value) {
    return read(in_out, *value);
}
```

(and tell matlab about `my_read`, not `read`) an optimizing compiler is likely to compile that in a single `jmp` machine instruction (which runs really fast).

Answer (score 2):

> So assuming that I can somehow change the definition to match the header, would my pointer function above be a valid substitution?

Yes.

And you would simply pass `&myInt` instead of `myInt` at the callsite.

> And if I can't change the source code, is there a substitution that I could make that would be possible with C? Like a reference C-substitute that would still allow for the same definition?

No.

If MATLAB requires C calling convention and such, then you're stuck with C features (mostly).

For what it's worth, I believe MATLAB is fine with C++; [the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mex-library.html) refers to "C/C++" throughout (which, we must assume, they mean to be "C and also C++").

So, looking at one final quote from your question:

> But I'm running it via a MATLAB mex file, so it may have to be in C, not C++. Since references are a C++ only thing, someone suggested changing

Stop. See whether it actually works as-is, first. Proceed from there.